# Vscode not showing html tags suggestion in react app

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, emmet

VScode suddenly stopped showing suggesions for html tags in react app. As you can see there is no suggestion appearing for html tags. But when I add the following lines to **settings.json** file, then the html tag suggestion appears but that time javascript suggestion stops appearing. Again when I remove the following lines from **settings.json**, I get javascript suggestions but html tag suggestions does not appears. How can I fix this?

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
  "javascript": "javascriptreact"
},
```

[image]

Comment: what about remove that from settings, by default both works, at least by me, i have checked vscode  and both suggestions are showing up

Comment: Share screenshot of VS Code after opening the file, both work for me too with `javascript: javascriptreact`

Comment: I tried by removing that line also. But still its the same.

Answer (score 2):

To add JSX/HTML autocomplete for `.js` files in React projects as follows

Add this in settings.json

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
     "javascript": "javascriptreact"
 },
 "emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
     "javascript": "jsx"
 }
```

Comment: When I add these lines, html suggestion appears, but I stop getting javascript syntax suggestions.